# Resizing Carousel in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, resize, carousel

I'm working on resizing the carousel on a different page (I have a bigger one on the index.html).  It looks like the forward and previous buttons are broken and do not function, although it does cycle like it should, just not on demand.

http://bootply.com/71275

Input to fix this would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code, your write this

```
<div id="aboutCarousel pull-right" class="carousel slide">
```

but you could write

```
<div id="aboutCarousel" class="carousel slide pull-right">
```

and all work fine ..

Comment: Thanks!  This worked perfectly.  Is there an explaination why it has to be on the end?  I'd rather learn the concept for the future than a one time fix.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: you can add only one id , and multiple class is possible , the order is enought ;) Courage !